# How to extract key phrases following specific characters using regex in R?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidytext

I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
ID | Tweet_ID | Tweet
1    12345      @sprintcare I did.
2    SPRINT     @12345 Please send us a Private Message.
3    45678      @apple My information is incorrect.
4    APPLE      @45678 What information is incorrect.
```

What I would like to do is some case_when statement to extract all the tweets that have the handle of the company name and ignore the numerical handles to create a new field.

Current code I'm playing around with but not succeeding with:

```
tweet_pattern <- " @[^0-9.-]\\w+"

Customer <- Customer %>% 
           Response_To_Comp = ifelse(str_detect(Tweet, tweet_pattern), 
                                str_extract(Tweet, tweet_pattern), 
                                NA_character_))
```

Desired output:

```
ID | Tweet_ID | Tweet                                    | Response_To_Comp
1    12345      @sprintcare I did.                         sprintcare
2    SPRINT     @12345 Please send us a Private Message.   NA
3    45678      @apple My information is incorrect.        apple
4    APPLE      @45678 What information is incorrect.      NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind regex to extract the text which comes after `'@'` and has one or more `A-Za-z` characters in them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tweet_pattern <- "(?<=@)[A-Za-z]+"

df %>%mutate(Response_To_Comp = str_extract(Tweet, tweet_pattern))

#  ID Tweet_ID                                    Tweet Response_To_Comp
#1  1    12345                       @sprintcare I did.       sprintcare
#2  2   SPRINT @12345 Please send us a Private Message.             <NA>
#3  3    45678      @apple My information is incorrect.            apple
#4  4    APPLE    @45678 What information is incorrect.             <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_detect` and `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
Customer %>%
    mutate(Response_to_Comp = case_when(str_detect(Tweet, "@[^0-9-]+") ~ 
      str_replace(Tweet, "@([A-Za-z]+)\\s+.*", "\\1")))
  ID Tweet_ID                                    Tweet Response_to_Comp
1  1    12345                       @sprintcare I did.       sprintcare
2  2   SPRINT @12345 Please send us a Private Message.             <NA>
3  3    45678      @apple My information is incorrect.            apple
4  4    APPLE    @45678 What information is incorrect.             <NA>
```

#### data

```
Customer <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Tweet_ID = c("12345", "SPRINT", "45678", 
"APPLE"), Tweet = c("@sprintcare I did.", "@12345 Please send us a Private Message.", 
"@apple My information is incorrect.", "@45678 What information is incorrect."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```